# How to make an infinitely recursive list in R: confuse [ and [[

Tags: r, list

Edit: this question is silly, I confused [ and [[ (thanks @josilber), but I can't delete it.

How can one make an infinitely recursive list, L == L[1], in R ?
A terrible way (for an R novice)
is to look at dataset `fmri` in package
[astsa](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/astsa):

```
data( fmri, package="astsa" )  # a list with fmri[1] == fmri[1][1] ... ??

print_recursive = function( x ){  # x x[1] x[1][1] ... while list
    for( j in 1:5 ){
        cat( class(x), len(x), names(x), "\n" )
        str(x)
        cat( "\n" )

        x = x[1]  # <-- wrong, should be x[[1]]
        if( class(x) != "list" )  break
    }
    x
}

x = print_recursive( fmri )
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to "How can one make an infinitely recursive list, L == L[1], in R" is that it is impossible, because you would need an infinite amount of memory to store a list of infinite recursive depth.

That being said, you can build a recursive list of a specified depth with a simple for loop, at each iteration creating a new list that stores the old list as one of its elements:

```
l <- list()
depth <- 50
for (k in seq(depth-1)) {
  l <- list(l)
}
```

You could write a recursive function to check the depth of a recursive list:

```
recursive.depth <- function(l) {
  if (!is.list(l)) 0
  else if (length(l) == 0) 1
  else 1+max(sapply(l, recursive.depth))
}
recursive.depth(l)
# [1] 50
recursive.depth(fmri)
# [1] 1
```

Getting back to the example from the question, the list you have is actually not recursive at all (it's just a list of matrices). The reason you think it is recursive is that indexing `l[1]` subsets the list (aka it returns the list with just its first element). For instance, consider the following very simple list:

```
(l <- list(2))
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
```

No matter how many times I subset with the `[` notation, I will get back the exact same list:

```
l[1]
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
l[1][1]
# [[1]]
# [1] 2
```

Running this list `l` through your `print_recursive` function will also result in an infinite loop. If you wanted to actually extract the first element of the list instead of subsetting the list itself, you should use the `[[` notation (e.g. `l[[1]]`).

Comment: `recursive.depth( fmri )` -> `Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion`

Comment: @denis: Was that the entire error message? There is often an additional bit of advice from that sort of error.

Comment: @denis I've updated my answer to discuss your case. In short `fmri` is not a recursive list at all and the confusion is coming from the `[` versus `[[` notation for indexing lists.